# Is stack.top().first() same as stack.top()?

Tags: c++, stack

A newbie question.

```
std::stack<int, int> stack;
```

Question:

is `stack.top().first()` same as `stack.top()`?

Comment: What is `std::stack<int, int>`? Did you try to compile that?

Comment: the second argument to stack<> should be a container, or blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You apparently have a stack of pairs (I'd guess that's really `std::stack<std::pair<int, int> >`, since `std::stack<int, int>` isn't even valid). `stack.top()` refers to the top item on the stack. Since (in your case) those are `std::pair<int, int>`, `.first` is the first `int` of the `pair` (and `.second` would give you the second int of the pair).

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not. `stack.top()` returns a reference to the most recently added item to the `stack`.

Calling `first` on that reference does not make sense at all unless that object has a method `first()`.